# Perl support Perl expression in replacement expression

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I have a little perl program that accepts 2 arguments, one the `FROM` string and the other the `TO` string.  It then runs a replace on any line entered by the user, using the `FROM` and `TO` on it.  My question is: How do I read if the `TO` statement is a dequoted Perl double-quoted string literal itself.

The program:

```
while (<STDIN>) {
        $_ =~ s/$ARGV[0]/$ARGV[1]/g;
        print STDOUT $_;
}

exit(0);
```

Example Arguments:

```
./program.pl '([aeiou])([aeiou])' '$2$1'
```

Text entered by user:

```
The rain in spain is always on the plain.
```

Since the `TO` string is dequoted Perl double-quoted string literal itself, the output by the program SHOULD be:

```
The rian in spian is always on the plian.
```

But instead is:

```
The r$2$1 in sp$2$1 is always on the pl$2$1n.
```

How can I get the expression to evaluate if the `$ARGV[1]` is dequoted Perl double-quoted string literal and do it?

Comment: If you use single quotes, the expression is going to be interpreted as is, and that's what you get. If you use double quotes, it's going to be interpreted *before* so they will be evaluated to the null string. Passing expressions on the command line is probably not the best way of doing that. Besides, if you are going this kind of thing [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) is probably better suited, and can work the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does what you want:

```
use String::Substitution qw( gsub_modify );

gsub_modify($_, $ARGV[0], $ARGV[1]);
```

Comment: A bit of context and explanation would help make this answer useful.